# How to show a name instead of id in a ListItemView with LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I am a Kotlin newbie and seems like I stuck in simpliest case. I try to use a right architecture but cannot understand the following. I create a simple school schedule application for my son. There is a Teacher class and a Subject class. Both are data classes in a room database. The Subject has a teacher_id. I have a RecyclerView with a list of subjects. The idea is to show a teacher's name in a subject card. But I cannot understand how to get and show teacher's name instead of subject.teacher_id using best/right practices.

SubjectsViewModel fragment:

```
class SubjectsViewModel(
    val database: SchoolScheduleDao,
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val db = database

...

    val subjects_list = db.getAllSubjects()
    val teachers_list = db.getAllTeachers()

...

    fun getTeacherFromList(teacher_id: Long): String {

        var tName:String = ""
        var lTeacher: Teacher? = teachers_list.value?.find { it.teacherId == teacher_id }

        if (lTeacher != null){
            tName = lTeacher.firstName + " " + lTeacher.secondName + " " + lTeacher.thirdName
        }

        return tName
    }

    ...
}
```

SubjectsAdapter fragment:

```
class  SubjectsAdapter(val clickListener: SubjectsListener): ListAdapter<Subject, SubjectsAdapter.ViewHolder>(SubjectsDiffCallback()) {

    class ViewHolder private constructor (val binding: ListItemSubjectBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding =
                    ListItemSubjectBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }

        fun bind(item: Subject, clickListener: SubjectsListener) {

            binding.subject = item

            val res = binding.root.context.resources

            binding.subjectName.text = item.name
            binding.roomNumber.text = item.roomNumber
            binding.teacherOfSubject.text = /*??? how to get Teacher.Name from here? I suppose if I use my SubjectsViewModel.getTeacherFromList(subject.teacher_id) here it is not a good practice*/

            binding.clickListener = clickListener
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.bind(getItem(position)!!, clickListener)

    }

}

...

class SubjectsListener(val clickListener: (ts: Subject) -> Unit) {

    fun onClick(subject: Subject) = clickListener(subject)

}
```

Please hint me a right direction

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aJsh6P00c0&t=724s&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers this should help you relating subjects to teachers. can have 1 to many

Comment: I think the main point here is that you need to pass an object to the adapter that contains all the information you need to show in the UI. Thus, you need to add the Teacher name to the Student class in your case

Comment: Thank you, guys. I just discovered a room's "Define relationships between objects" guide and it seems like it is exactly my case - to define a composite object with a relationship inside.